# Search for similar item from millions of items, based on embedding

Tags: elasticsearch, search, similarity, cosine-similarity

I have 50M ( Millions ) images and image captions.
I have already extracted feature representation of all 50M,

- Images representation using VGG model.
- Image captions representation using Bert model.

When I get new image & caption representation, I want to find Best N similar items based cosine similarity from 50M.

What are the fastest ways to get similar items & cosine score ?
Does Elastic Search can solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Check **Vector search** paragraph of [this page](https://vitali-fedulov.github.io/similar.pictures/research.html). The document contains relevant examples and links to AWS, Google vector search services.

[Milvus](https://github.com/milvus-io/milvus) vector search engine is becoming popular too (it is open-source).

Comment: Is it possible to do same using Elastic Search ?